# How to use factory in Laravel 8 to create dummy table data in tinker and connect them?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-factory

I have 2 tables **users** and **posts** that I need to connect. I am creating dummy data using tinker in Laravel 8 with the help of `factory` library. It's working all fine with the `users` and I am using this to create users data:

```php
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->faker->name,
        'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
}
```

In `php artisan tinker` I wrote:

```php
User::factory()->count(5)->create();
```

Now, I want to populate the `posts` table accordingly and connect these tables together by using 'name' from the `users` table and `user_id` field of `posts` table. I have no idea what to write in the `user_id` section. I am writing the code for the `posts` table below:

```php
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'title'=>$this->faker->sentence,
        'user_id'=>"",
        'name'=>$this->faker->name,
        'body'=>$this->faker->paragraph
    ];
}
```

Please help me with the `user_id` column. what should I fill here so that I could get the names from the `users` table and fill it in the `posts` table's `user_id` column.

**Users Table**
[image]

**Posts Table**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the `user` `factory` lifecycle and create `posts` after a `user` has been created.

In your `UserFactory`, override the `configure` method:

```
public function configure()
{
    return $this->afterCreating(function (User $user) {
        $iters = mt_rand(0, 5);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $iters; $i++) {
            $user->posts()->save(new Post());
        }
    });
}
```

That will create some new `posts` for you and assign them to the `user` through the `posts` relationship I assume you have defined on your `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

In the `PostFactory` we could assign a random `User` `id` as per the following example:

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'title'=>$this->faker->sentence,
        'user_id'=> User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
        'name'=>$this->faker->name,
        'body'=>$this->faker->paragraph
    ];
}
```